# Standing desk mat with office chairs?

Tags: health

We have standing desks and office chairs with wheels.

I want to get a mat to stand on, but if I had one under my desk i'd have to move it every time I wanted to sit in my chair.

Are the're standing desk mats that wheeled office chairs can roll over or work with?

Is there a solution to this problem? Is this the wrong forum for this, seemed like the most appropriate one.

Comment: This is not really an answer to your question, but I have a mat too, and I find that since I don't transition between standing/sitting very often, it's not really a problem to move the mat away. I transition roughly every couple hours.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not applicable within the context of this site.

Comment: @rrirower - I agree, but your wording is odd. You're essentially saying "I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is off-topic". Close votes should inform the asker exactly what makes it off-topic. In this case, it's because it doesn't have to do with exercise, but furniture convenience.

Comment: I am migrating this to The Workplace where it is more on topic, however you might do better to ask about the problems of a mat + chair rather than specific mat recommendations.